# Laravelcollective in Cloud9 without composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cloud9-ide, laravelcollective

I'm using Laravel 5.1 in Cloud9 IDE but cannot do a composer update (permission denied), that way I cannot install laravelcollective (Forms/Html) from composer.
I try copy the laravelcollective from my local PC and edit the App providers and aliases but get the error:

```
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to `chmod 775` your `storage` folder which is located in root directory of the laravel framework if you are using laravel 5 or `app/storage` if you are using laravel 4.

This should solve your problem

Comment: I ran "chmod 775 storage" but keep getting the error: `[ErrorException] file_put_contents(/home/ubuntu/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-laravelcollective$html.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: You should do a recursive `chmod` `sudo chmod -R 775 storage` inside root laravel folder if you are using laravel 5 or `sudo chmod -R 775 app/storage` inside laravel's root folder if you are using laravel 4.

Comment: It works. I did 1) `sudo su`, 2) `chmod -R 775 storage`, 3) `composer update`. Maybe a simple `sudo su` and a `composer update` would solve.